# Need to export xlsx file from local in Javascript to convert into JSON

Tags: javascript

I wanted to import xlsx file from the local path convert it into JSON & view into the browser using HTML, but it's showing error:
**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/----/details.xlsx' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.**

If I run html file using the Live Server extension it works but directly opening the html file doesn't work.

I am using below function to import file from local.

```js
function ImportFile() {
  var excelUrl = "./details.xlsx";

  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open("get", excelUrl, true);
  oReq.responseType = "blob";
  oReq.onload = function () {
    excelFileToJSON(oReq.response);
  };
  oReq.send(null);
}
```

Comment: You cannot use XHR to load `file://` URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the excel file then parse it first before you can convert it to any kind of format that you want.

```
// Method to upload a valid excel file
function upload() {
  var files = document.getElementById('file_upload').files;
  if(files.length==0){
    alert("Please choose any file...");
    return;
  }
  var filename = files[0].name;
  var extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".")).toUpperCase();
  if (extension == '.XLS' || extension == '.XLSX') {
      excelFileToJSON(files[0]);
  }else{
      alert("Please select a valid excel file.");
  }
}
 
//Method to read excel file and convert it into JSON 
function excelFileToJSON(file){
    try {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
      reader.onload = function(e) {
 
          var data = e.target.result;
          var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
              type : 'binary'
          });
          var result = {};
          workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
              var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
              if (roa.length > 0) {
                  result[sheetName] = roa;
              }
          });
          //displaying the json result
          var resultEle=document.getElementById("json-result");
          resultEle.value=JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);
          resultEle.style.display='block';
          }
      }catch(e){
          console.error(e);
      }
}
```

source: [Javacodepoint](https://javacodepoint.com/convert-excel-file-data-to-json-in-javascript/)

Above code will parse XLSX file using [xlsx package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) and convert it to JSON format. You can alter the formatting output as far as you like.